# how to use Panel in Expression Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

In windows form, I can toggle between panel 1 and panel 2.
I mean after the button is clicked from panel 1, i want to show panel2. After button is clicked from panel 2, I want to show panel 1. I want to do this in expression blend. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook up button click events and set the Visibility property of panel to collapsed(to hide the panel) or to visible(to show), and just toggle between them to show the corrent panel.